# Intuition Behind the Definition of Prudence?

Tags: macroeconomics, utility, saving, definition

I'm having trouble seeing *why* an agent is said to exhibit "prudence" when u'''($\cdot$) > 0. How does having a utility function with a strictly positive third derivative make an agent act "prudently"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that prudence is related to the theory of [precautionary savings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precautionary_savings#Theoretical_motivation)?

Answer (score 5):

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prudence#In_economics) article:

> Economists describe a consumer as "prudent" if he or she saves more when faced with riskier future income. This additional saving is called precautionary saving.

For risk averse consumers with thrice differentiable utility  $u^{\prime\prime\prime}>0$ is a [necessary and sufficient condition](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2296725) for consumers to save more for tomorrow when they are really unsure what is going to happen in the future.

Comment: A reference for "is a necessary and sufficient condition for consumers" would be nice!

Comment: This is ratherh close to being a link-only answer.